# First Whitney-Stiefel class of normal bundle of the open Mobius band in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, characteristic-classes

Let $M$ be the open Mobius band (a $2$-manifold without boundary) embedded in $\Bbb R^3$, and let $\nu$ and $\tau$ denote the normal bundle and tangent bundle of $M$, respectively. How do we know that $w_1(\nu)$ is nonzero?

My attempt: By the Whitney duality theorem, $w(\nu)=w(\tau)^{-1}=w(M)^{-1}$. Since $M$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, $w(M)=w(S^1)=1$, so $w(\nu)=1$. Something must be wrong but I can't see it.

Comment: For starters, $\nu$ is non-orientable, so $w_1 \ne 0$. Similarly for $\tau$. You’re saying that the tangent bundle of $M$ is bundle equivalent to the tangent bundle of $S^1$? Huh?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. I thought $w$ is a homotopy invariant. By the way, is the orientability criterion of $w_1$ an elementary fact? I am reading almost half of the book Characteristic classes of Milnor, but I can't see such a statement

Comment: I know that *closed* homotopy equivalent manifolds have the same Stiefel-Whitney classes (in the sense that a homotopy equivalence maps Stiefel-Whitney classes to Stiefel-Whitney classes), but this result is not true if at least one manifold is not closed (as your example demonstrates.)

Comment: You do know about naturality and the SW class of the tautological line bundle on $\Bbb RP^1$. If a line bundle is non-orientable, its pullback to a certain $S^1$ is this tautological line bundle.